# Can particles enherit constraints from their render object?

Tags: particles

Example:I have a large sphere that emits particles
and a tiny sphere that the will become each individual particle .

If the original tiny sphere gets a [Limit distance](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/transform/limit_distance.html) to surface constraint,
can each particle also inherit the constraint that the original one has?

So that the particles will stick to the surface of a mesh while moving, even if the mesh is irregular.

I can get similar effect with forces but its very delicate and can fly off the surface easily.
[image]

Comment: Well i know that you can orient particles to camera via an inherited track to constraint. But that is orientation i dont knownif you can apply cobstraints to position of each aprricle. Doubtful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, no. Particles do not inherit constraints. If you want particles to stick to a moving object, make it a collision object and play around with the dampening and stick values.

Comment: yea,looks like it, but can you pitch the idea on rightclickselect.com for me  please? I cant undelete my account on it. long story

Comment: I believe that you can do that best. I don't have an account either.